# Partial type family application

Tags: haskell, ghc, type-families

This recursive definition of `T` fails to type-check.

```hs
class C a where
  type T a :: Type

newtype Compose (f :: Type -> Type) (g :: Type -> Type) (a :: Type) = Compose {getCompose :: f (g a)}

instance C (Maybe a) where
  type T (Maybe a) = NP (Compose T Identity) '[a]
```

Specific error:

```
    • The associated type family ‘T’ should have 1 argument, but has been given none
    • In the type instance declaration for ‘T’
      In the instance declaration for ‘C (Maybe a)’
   |
32 |   type T (Maybe a) = NP (Compose T Identity) '[a]
   |        ^
```

1. Why is GHC unable to do this?
2. Is there a workaround?

The real class/instance looks like this:

```hs
instance Ema (MultiSite models) where
  type RouteFor (MultiSite models) = NP (Compose RouteFor Site) models
```

This says that "the route for a multisite is an n-ary product of the routes for the individual sites", hence `RouteFor` has to be defined recursively.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Type families are unmatchable and must be fully saturated. This means they can not be passed partially applied as an argument. This is basically what the error message says

> • The associated type family ‘`T`’ should have 1 argument, but has been given none

At the present time this is not distinguished at the kind level (see [Unsaturated type families](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/pull/242) proposal) but there is a very clear distinction within GHC.

According to `:kind` both `T` and `Identity` have the same kind while in reality `Identity` is **M**atchable and `T` is **U**nmatchable:

```hs
Identity :: Type -> @M Type
T        :: Type -> @U Type
```

Because the arguments of `Compose` are `Type -> @M Type` you cannot pass an unmatchable type family. The type language is first order! ([Higher-Order Type-Level Programming in Haskell](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2019/03/unsaturated-type-families-icfp-2019.pdf)) and there is no way to define `Compose` that accepts an unmatchable function at the moment.

If you compare the kind of the slightly modified `T1` and `T2`, the first one is unmatchable in both arguments while the second is matchable in its second argument

```
type  C1 :: Type -> @M Constraint
class C1 a where
  --   T1 :: Type -> @U Type -> @U Type
  type T1 a (b :: Type) :: Type

type  C2 :: Type -> @M Contraint
class C2 a where
  --   T2 :: Type -> @U Type -> @M Type
  type T2 a :: Type -> Type
```

A possibility is to wrap it in a (matchable) newtype

```hs
type    Wrapp'T :: Type -> @M Type
newtype Wrapp'T a = Wrapp'd (T a)

instance C (Maybe a) where
  type T (Maybe a) = NP (Compose Wrapp'T Identity) '[a]
```